# Bitmask use in C

Tags: c, bitmap

I need to extract the the bits 2,3, and 4 from an uint8 and interpret it as an in.

For example if I have 0x1A and 0x1C as mask:

0x1A 0001 1010 Value

0x1c 0001 1100 mask

if I do 0x1A & 0x1C I get

0001 1000

which is 24 in base when instead I need just the three bits that are masked 110 (6 in base 10)

Comment: And so what have you tried? What happened? What did you expect?

Comment: Hm- "three bits that are masked 110" is actually *two* bits. Only `1`s define the mask.

Comment: The mask is 0x1c which has three non-zero bits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [bitwise shift operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bit_shifts) `>>` to shift the value 2 bits to the right.

Either mask and then shift:

```
result = (value & 0x1C) >> 2;
```

Or shift and then mask (note the mask must be shifted too):

```
result = (value >> 2) & 7;
```

Makes no difference; both approaches will transform the 8-bit value *a<sub>7</sub>a<sub>6</sub>a<sub>5</sub>a<sub>4</sub>a<sub>3</sub>a<sub>2</sub>a<sub>1</sub>a<sub>0</sub>* into 00000*a<sub>4</sub>a<sub>3</sub>a<sub>2</sub>*.